# Moving a a json string into a VB.NET dropdownbox

Tags: json, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I receive the following json string from an API call, and I want to populate a VB.NET Dropdownbox with the 'Essd' + 'Frequency' in the Textfield (e.g. 'Common - 5.5 GHz') and 'Essd' in the Valuefield.

I have found lots of example here of simple one dimensional and jaggered, multi-dimensional, but nothing that manages a simple 2D Array.

I almost done my head trying to resolve this.

json String Below:

```
{
  "E4:95:6E:4D:3E:57": {
    "Frequency": "2.412 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-58 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "52/70 ",
    "Encryption": "on",
    "Essid": "Guest",
    "Wpa": "WPA2 "
  },
  "FC:34:97:76:D5:91": {
    "Frequency": "2.412 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-23 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "70/70 ",
    "Encryption": "on",
    "Essid": "Common",
    "Wpa": "WPA2 "
  },
  "10:06:45:A7:B0:9B": {
    "Frequency": "2.412 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-58 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "52/70 ",
    "Encryption": "on",
    "Essid": "Optus_A7B099",
    "Wpa": "WPA2 "
  },
  "BC:30:D9:DA:29:8B": {
    "Frequency": "2.452 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-62 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "48/70 ",
    "Encryption": "on",
    "Essid": "TelstraDA2989",
    "Wpa": "WPA2 "
  },
  "FC:34:97:76:D5:94": {
    "Frequency": "5.2 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-26 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "70/70 ",
    "Encryption": "on",
    "Essid": "Common",
    "Wpa": "WPA2 "
  },
  "FC:34:97:74:E7:F4": {
    "Frequency": "5.2 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-48 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "62/70 ",
    "Encryption": "on",
    "Essid": "Common",
    "Wpa": "WPA2 "
  },
  "10:06:45:A7:B0:9C": {
    "Frequency": "5.2 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-70 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "40/70 ",
    "Encryption": "on",
    "Essid": "Optus_A7B099_5GHz",
    "Wpa": "WPA2 "
  },
  "FC:34:97:76:D5:98": {
    "Frequency": "5.5 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-34 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "70/70 ",
    "Encryption": "on",
    "Essid": "",
    "Wpa": "WPA2 "
  },
  "BC:30:D9:DD:DB:8F": {
    "Frequency": "2.412 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-66 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "44/70 ",
    "Encryption": "on",
    "Essid": "TelstraDDDB8D",
    "Wpa": "WPA2 "
  },
  "F8:CA:59:49:BE:37": {
    "Frequency": "2.462 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-75 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "35/70 ",
    "Encryption": "on",
    "Essid": "My WiFi you know like Borat",
    "Wpa": "WPA2 "
  },
  "9E:7B:EF:FE:19:F8": {
    "Frequency": "2.412 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-71 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "39/70 ",
    "Encryption": "on",
    "Essid": "DIRECT-F8-HP ENVY 5000 series",
    "Wpa": "WPA2 "
  },
  "FC:34:97:74:E7:F0": {
    "Frequency": "2.412 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-51 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "59/70 ",
    "Encryption": "on",
    "Essid": "Common",
    "Wpa": "WPA2 "
  },
  "FC:34:97:74:E7:F8": {
    "Frequency": "5.5 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-51 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "59/70 ",
    "Encryption": "on",
    "Essid": "",
    "Wpa": "WPA2 "
  },
  "FA:8F:CA:7A:AD:00": {
    "Frequency": "2.452 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-65 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "45/70 ",
    "Encryption": "off",
    "Essid": ""
  },
  "12:06:45:A7:B0:9D": {
    "Frequency": "5.2 GHz",
    "Signal_level": "-70 dBm  ",
    "Quality": "40/70 ",
    "Encryption": "on",
    "Essid": "\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00",
    "Wpa": "WPA2 "
  }
```

Any help or hints greatly apricated.

Comment: Are you looking for a library to parse the JSON?

Comment: No, no library, just code.

Comment: As I go through this moving the data to a DataTable seems a better idea, this is how I see the setup of the DT:
Public Class Json2Datatable
    Public Shared Function 2Array() As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("MAC")
        dt.Columns.Add("Frequency")
        dt.Columns.Add("Signal_level")
        dt.Columns.Add("Quality")
        dt.Columns.Add("Encryption")
        dt.Columns.Add("Essid")
        dt.Columns.Add("Wpa")
    End Function
End Class

Comment: You might find it cleaner to use the Paste as Json classes (From the edit menu in Paste Special) then it's a relatively simple process to Deserialize your json to typed object collections